# Using the F word in the middle of the word

Tags: expressions, offensive-language

Not sure if I can use the F words here, therefore I will refer to it as f*** or f***in

I know that we can use F word in the middle of the sentence

like

> You may **f***in** not do that

or

> She is **f***in** hot.

I am not sure where I heard this but I recall someone was using it in the middle of the word such as

> abso-**f***in**-lutely = absolutely

or

> ex-**f***in**-cuse me = excuse me

I know it is not alright to use this kind of language in home or work or any other place, yet many people use it.
So is this right way to use the F word in the middle of the word or it is wrong

Comment: A recent Lexiconvalley episode talked about it at length (like 5 episodes ago, they have transcripts). I can't infere a definite rule and I don't think you really need one

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because *there are no rules about this* -- we can't help you with it.

Comment: It’s more appropriate to say f***in’.

Comment: Assuming you are going to use the F word at all, the important thing when using it in the middle of another word is to ensure the end result has a good rhythm. A word with more than two syllables can be broken in several places, some of which will not work well. It's a matter of style.

Comment: @KannE I remember learning about infixes - I was trying to think what they were called.

Comment: Other swear words have been known to be used in a similar way, usually inserted into a longer word like _absolutely_.

Comment: Acceptability varies with situation. Offensive language probably outweighs correctness of word formation when it cones to unacceptability, but there are plenty of examples of the type of word-or-is-it you mention in various areas / genres. Looking at the rare example 'abso-very-lutely', which probably avoids the vulgarity problem (though some would say it's tarnished by association, ie has a vulgar connotation), it's obviously a quirky but transparent usage. Fine in very informal contexts, but to be avoided elsewhere.

Comment: The usage is mostly seen in situations where there is some degree of alliteration.  "Fanf***intastic" is the one I'm most familiar with.  It's used for emphasis, of course.

Comment: @KannE A more family-friendly infix is "whole" - as in the expression "a-whole-nother ballgame"

Answer (score -3):

I would say that this is the right way to use it in the middle of a word; however, I don't encourage its use in public. The best way to use it is somewhere in a sentence, because it makes more sense.

Comment: We British recognise 'abso-bloody-lutely'. and similar constructions.